# Getting "undefined method" when trying to access my static variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, variables, methods, static, undefined

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m having trouble defining a static variable in my class.  I have

```
class MainService < Abstractmy_objectFinderService

  # class variables 
  @@my_object_desc_link_template = "https://results.Main.com/mobile/results/my_objects?_dc=1467745366092&eventID=21476"

…

          event_link = MainService.my_object_data_link_template.sub( %r{intervalID=[^&]+}, "intervalID=#{interval_id}" )
                                          .sub( %r{eventID=[^&]+}, "eventID=#{event_id}" )
                                          .sub( %r{my_objectID=[^&]+}, "my_objectID=#{my_object_id}" )
```

but when I run my code I get the error

```
undefined method `my_object_desc_link_template' for MainService:Class
```

What else do I need to do to define the static variable successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby you don't initialize variables outside method blocks.  That said I'm going to guess what your code sample does and rewrite it completely:

```
class MainService
  BASE_URL =  "https://results.Main.com/mobile/results/my_objects"
  DEFAULT_PARAMS = {_dc: 1467745366092}

  def self.event_link(interval_id, my_object_id, event_id)
    params = {intervalID: interval_id,
              eventID: event_id,
              my_object_ID: my_object_id}

    "#{BASE_URL}?#{DEFAULT_PARAMS.merge(params).to_query}"
  end
end
```

Then call it from anywhere with the event_link class method:

```
MainService.event_link(1, 2, 3)
=> https://results.Main.com/mobile/results/my_objects?_dc=1467745366092&eventID=3&intervalID=1&my_object_ID=2"
```

Let me know if you really wanted to use class variables instead.